# Passing input stream to video view

Tags: java, android, video, inputstream, android-videoview

I have input stream that i need to pass it as to Video view:

But it says OutOfMemoryError

Here is my code:

```
//to convert input stream to string
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        is.close();

        return sb.toString();
    }

//passing that string to video view
String total = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(total);
videoHolder.setVideoURI(uri);
```

How to acheive this?

**EDIT**

here is the stack trace

```
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.abc.Utility.Utils.convertStreamToString(Utils.java:196)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.abc.xyz.VideoPlayer.onCreate(VideoPlayer.java:257)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1172)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-17 17:46:34.242: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Are you casting a video file to a String object? :D Or to rephrase - loading a video file in a string object?

Comment: @CommonsWare i have posted the stack trace

Comment: Where are you getting this stream from? Please bear in mind that `setVideoURI()` takes a *URI*, such as a `file://` or `http://` path.

Comment: the input stream is a classLoader.getResourceAsStream,

Comment: I don't think you can pass raw video data to `VideoView`. In the past I have implemented a simple local http server and passed the http://localhost address to VideoView. This works fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare check out my answer below

Answer (score 4):

ok i have solved it myself but it has a 3 to 4 seconds delay before the video file starts

Hope it helps some one :

```
public static String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
      if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
            return path;
        } else {
           URL url = new URL(path);
           URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
           cn.connect();
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
            temp.deleteOnExit();
            String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
                int numread = stream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true);
            try {
                stream.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
              //  Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            return tempPath;
        }
    }
```